# Cannot convert column into bool

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to update a column in a PySpark Dataframe using when. I am checking for multiple conditions by using an array. I get the error `'Cannot convert column into bool'`.
I am assuming this is because I am using `in` to check across a list of values. The error offers alternatives for other things like and (&) and or (|) but nothing for in.
Is there some way to do a check against all the values instead of chaining several when statements? Code is below

```
affirm = ['yes', 'y', 'Y', 'Yes', 'YES']
neg = ['no', 'n', 'N', 'No', 'NO']
new_df.withColumn('resp', when(col("resp") in affirm, 'Yes').when(col("resp") in neg, 'No').otherwise('null'))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
new_df.withColumn('resp', when(col("resp").isin(*affirm), 'Yes').when(col("resp").isin(*neg), 'No').otherwise('null'))
```

[See docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.isin).

Comment: thanks this worked! just wondering, what does the * do in front of affirm?

Comment: @greenteam `*` and `**` are for unpack list and dicts. You can read more [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)